# FSharp.Data - Save the downloaded file using the website responded name?

Tags: f#, f#-data

I have the following function to download file.

```
let download url folder name =
    use out = File.Create(Path.Combine(folder, name))
    Http.RequestStream(url, cookieContainer = cc, headers = headers)
        .ResponseStream.CopyTo(out)
```

However, I need another download function which just use the name from the website. How to get the name?

```
let download url folder =
    let name = .... // get from the default name set by the website?
    use out = File.Create(Path.Combine(folder, name))
    Http.RequestStream(url, cookieContainer = cc, headers = headers)
        .ResponseStream.CopyTo(out)
```

Comment: I belive your url contain filename used by remote server. For example: url http://example.com/files/image.png contain filename "image.png"

Comment: Yes, it's true for a lot of web pages. But sometimes the urls don't have anything look like file name and the server will response with a file name.

Comment: Can you get Headers from server responce?